# execute JS serverside on ASP net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want my server to run a javascript serverside and I don't have any clue how to do this or at least whether it's possible or not.

I **don't**  want to run my javascript on any client, because it will deal with crucial information(or at least stuff, nobody should see).

If you know how to do this or have any idea about it, let me know.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Javascript is meant to run in client browser.

Comment: I know, but I have a probelm which can be only done in JS but contains information that should not be revealed to any enduser.

Comment: there is no reason to run js on server side in your case (you can take node.js if you really want). Seems like you not really understand what you want to do.

Comment: javascript work on the browser. So if you want your code to run on the server side, you better stick with server side languages or use node.js to run the server with javascript. But still, I believe you can solve all the server side related problem with ASP.net. So I think you better research how to solve the problem with ASP.net rather then executing JS at serverside.